# How do I display random blog posts, favoring posts with high ratings?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

Let's say I have a Blog posts table that has a rating field which indicates the quality of the post. What is the most efficient way to randomly find a post, with a higher chance of returning a highly ranked post?

I will be implementing this in PHP, MySQL, and possibly Lucene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a "weighted random" ordering, such as:

```
SELECT title, body FROM posts ORDER BY (score+1) * RAND() DESC LIMIT 5
```

The +1 is there to allow posts with 0 score to be selected. <s>Depending on the average score of your post you may have to multiply the score by another constant factor (e.g. `0.5*score+1`)</s>.

Depending on the distribution of your scores you may want to transform your score, for instance with `LOG(score)` or `SQRT(score)`.

Comment: How will this method scale in terms of when the database gets to be quite large: e.g. 10k+ number of posts? (Not that there are so many, but scalability is the issue) Will using Lucene prove to be a better method?

Comment: I never used Lucene, so I cannot help you with that. However, it is true that `RAND` gets slow with large datasets. See http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,163940,163940#msg-163940 for possible workarounds.

Comment: What would multiplying by `0.5` achieve?

Comment: @lonesomeday: actually, I originally thought to add the random component, case in which multiplying by 0.5 makes sense... now that I think about it in this case it doesn't anymore. I corrected my post, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: multiplying with 0.5, you give less importance(weight) to the ratings.  you can also involve number of ratings in the sorting so that small number of ratings won't effect the sorting that much.

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution would be to include calls to `RAND()` and to the `rating` column and multiplying them together:

```
SELECT title, content FROM blog_posts ORDER BY (rating + 1) * RAND() DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If you found this gave too much precedence to items with a high rating, you could use `SQRT`:

```
SELECT title, content FROM blog_posts ORDER BY SQRT(rating + 1) * RAND() DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: As I was saying in my answer, you'll need a +1 on `rating` if you want to select posts with 0 score.

Answer (score 0):

SQL COMMAND :

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '$randomly_generated_ids' ORDER BY ratings ASC
```

for example **$randomly_generated_ids** can be "13,10,5,20"

Details for : [**ORDER BY**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Comment: You're selecting at random and then ordering by rating. He wants to randomly select posts favouring high ratings in the selection. There's a little difference here.